# Powershell Start-ThreadJob does not respect ThrottleLimit parameter

Tags: powershell, batch-processing, parallel.foreach, winrm, powershell-core

Here is the code:

```
function sh {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object[]]$Lab
    )    
    if ($Lab.Count -ne 0) {                
        
        $Lab | ForEach-Object {
            $null = Start-ThreadJob -ScriptBlock {
                param($ComputerName)
                Stop-Computer -Force -ComputerName $ComputerName
            } -ThrottleLimit 250 -ArgumentList $_
        }
    }
}
```

The script just shuts down a lot of workstations.. and there are less then 250 computers, but if never able to spawn threads as needed and I see computers shut down in batches of ~30-40.. Why so? I do specify ThrottleLimit

I also tried:

```
ForEach-Object -UseNewRunspace -Parallel {} -AsJob

ForEach-Object -UseNewRunspace -Parallel {
        Invoke-Command -Computername ...etc
} -AsJob
```

None of the methods provide simultaneous true parallel execution at scale!
The thing I didn't tried:
Working with `Runspaces` - Shutdown every machine in new `Runspace` may it work?

Comment: Does your CPU have 250 cores? You can schedule all the threads you want, won't help if there's no capacity to execute it

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no my CPU doesn't have 250 cores but currently my system somehow able to spawn 3620 threads (in Task Manager I see it).. Why not to spawn 250 for powershell

Comment: You can spawn them fine - that's just carving out a bit of memory and a kernel handle - but they won't _execute_ their code in "true" parallel. As an analogy: you can drive 3620 cars onto a stretch of 6-lane highway, but you'll still only have 6 lanes of traffic

Comment: "The thing I didn't tried: Working with Runspaces - Shutdown every machine in new Runspace may it work?" Result will be the same, `Start-ThreadJob` and `ForEach-Object -Parallel` are wrappers of runspace.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Actually You are right.. I inspected thread creation for pwsh.exe process and it indeed creates threads as needed, with a noticeable delay however.. So yes... I wish async await would exist in powershell one day.

Comment: The delay likely stems from PowerShell trying to delay thread creation until the underlying pool actually has capacity - which makes sense from a memory utilization point of view. Having better async primitives in PowerShell would indeed be nice, but it wouldn't have made any difference here - CPU scheduling would still be the bottleneck

Comment: stop-computer computer1,computer2,computer3 already runs in parallel.  So does invoke-command.